# Constructors can only be inherited DIRECTLY from the base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer

I have a base class A, that defines some constructors.

Then I have classes B1, B2, B3 that inherit from A.

None of these are meant to be instantiated.  Instead, I have classes C11, C12, C13 inheriting from B1, and so on.

C11, C12 etc. all need A's constructors.

I don't think I can write `using A::A;` in class C11, for instance, right?

The only way to get these constructors (other than cutting and pasting them) is for B1 to say `using A::A;` and C11 to say `using B1::B1;`?

Note my question isn't about what a particular compiler supports, but what the spec allows, so "just test it" isn't really an answer to this particular question.

Comment: While there is a lot of variance in C++ implementations, that variance is usually about complex template stuff or arcane aspects of the object model or whatever. When it's something as simple as name scoping or which base class names in a concrete class can be used in a member initializer list, it's entirely reasonable to assume that if a compiler forbids it, it's because the standard forbids it. Admittedly, VLAs is a counter-example.

Comment: @NicolBolas I also see things the other way.  If it's something obvious the compiler can support, it's often done as an extension and sometimes without warning.  g++ doesn't need the class specifier on a method pointer for instance (though does warn that it's not standard).and that seems a little bit related (in that it's about flexibility in finding members).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a quote from the standard, then here goes:

> **[namespace.udecl]/3** ... If a *using-declarator* names a constructor, its *nested-name-specifier* shall name a direct base class of the class being defined.